# Crystal Report Excel Export

Tags: crystal-reports

Iam Using Crystal Report 10 in our Java Web Application.We Have Developed Lots of reports using Crystal Reports. but we are not getting options to Export Excel.. how can i get it?
Error:Iam Getting Export Excel Option in Crystal Report10

Answer (score 0):

Export options are controlled by the installation options when you install the Crystal Reports Engine on the client.   Re-install ( which will actually take you through a Modify vs Install ) will allow you to add the missing items.